# Overlay image on video in ffmpeg for android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

When i add image on video but my image cut off right side in ffmpeg android studio so how to give image width?

**[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y21Si.jpg**

below is my command:

1. String command = "-i '" + uri.toString() + "'"
   + " -i '" + layer.getAbsolutePath() + "'"
   + " -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay="+getX+":"+getY+"[outVideo],[0:a]volume=1:[audio0]"
   -map [outVideo] -map [audio0]"
   + "  '"
   + mDestinationPath + "'";

Answer (score 0):

[1]You can getx = 0 so image not cut right side.

```
getX = 0;
```

String command = "-i '" + uri.toString() + "'"
+ " -i '" + layer.getAbsolutePath() + "'"
+ " -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay="+getX+":"+getY+"[outVideo],[0:a]volume=1:[audio0]" -map [outVideo] -map [audio0]"
+ "  '"
+ mDestinationPath + "'";

**[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIBHn.jpg**